# Suites vs Specs Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, test-suite

I have recently picked up a project using Protractor.

I am having troubles understand the *difference between a suite and a specs*. I am also having trouble with a suites when I am running a folder of test's after that folder is ran I run another folder of test and it fails all the test. Any help would be great listed below is what or suite looks like.

Example:

```
suites: {
    CSRSmokeTest: '../smoke/Video/**.js'
    DesktopSmokeTest: '../smoke/deskTop/**.js'
},
```

Comment: A suite is one or more specs, logically grouped. For instance, if you only want certain tests to run during a Smoke test, you'd put those specs (tests) into a Suite for Smoke Tests.

Comment: i've grouped my specs as config.js file
specs:[testcase1.js,testcase2.js,testcase3.js] and each spec is executed one after another is their a more better way to organise my specs and run

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Suites are incredibly useful for organizing your tests.

The question actually goes down to differences between a suite and a test case in general. Quote from the [wikipedia "Test suite" definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_suite):

> a collection of test cases that are intended to be used to test a
>   software program to show that it has some specified set of behaviours.
>   A test suite often contains detailed instructions or goals for each
>   collection of test cases and information on the system configuration
>   to be used during testing.

In other words, a test suite is a collection of specs/testcases united by a *common property, logic*. For instance, you may have suites for different types of functionality of your application, `homepage`, `search` etc:

```
suites: {
  homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
  search: [
    'tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
    'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js'
  ] 
},
```

And/or, you may have specs grouped into suites by the type of tests:

```
suites: {
  smoke: 'tests/e2e/smoke/*.js',
  performance: 'tests/e2e/performance/*.js'
},
```

Or, you may put all of your "regression" tests into a separate suite. Or, you can apply your own logic to group specs.

It is important to note that a *single spec can be a part of multiple test suites*.