# Protractor - how to restart browser between certain specs?

Tags: protractor

I have specs for subscriptions:

- with Facebook
- without Facebook

For specs with Facebook subscription I have to turn on `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` to clear browser cache from previously entered Facebook emails and passwords. For other subscriptions I have to turn `restartBrowserBetweenTests` off manually, every time. Is there any way in Protractor to restart browser only between certain specs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option/workaround would be to have 2 different protractor configs with different `restartBrowserBetweenTests` values and [`suites`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/page-objects#configuring-test-suites)/[`specs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331018/suites-vs-specs-protractor) defined.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I thought about it, I will do so I will not find any other solution. As for me it is not very comfortable. I also tried to use this code, but without any success:  
afterEach(function(){  browser.restart();  
});