# how to run spec priority wise in protractor

Tags: protractor

Can anyone help me out how to run spec in order, because the application which i am working has many specs and when i use command

> 'specs': '*.js',

all specs are executed but not in the order which i have written them, i don't want to special all my specs name in single spec like for example

> 'specs' : [ 'test1.js','test2.js',.... ]

because i have lots of specs.
Can anyone help me with how to run specs in order?
i want

> test1.js to be executed 1st,
>   test2.js to be executed 2nd and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `suites` are for, to organize your tests.  It's a parameter in your config file, i.e.

```
suites : {
    login: 'tests/login/*.spec.js,
}
```

You can also specify this as an array:

```
suites : {
    mySuite: [
        'test1.spec.js',
        'test2.spec.js'
    ]
}
```

These will execute in the order you specify here.  Here's a good answer describing the purpose of suites: [Suites vs Specs Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331018/suites-vs-specs-protractor)

Comment: @SuhailAhmed Glad it worked.  Please consider accepting the answer as correct to help others.