# How to declare the tests in different groups using plugins called jasmine-group or karma-jasmine-group

Tags: jasmine, e2e-testing, jasmine-node

Does anybody succeeded with using `jasmine-group` plugin for grouping jasmine tests and executing only certain group of tests

I have tried with [this plug-in](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-group) which is not executable after all the configurations according to the instructions

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you sure using `suites` (groups of tests) can't accomplish your objective?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331018/suites-vs-specs-protractor

Comment: Can you please check the karma-jasmine-group plugin, I have a requirement where i will declare each test in one describe(i,e suite), I want to give a group name for each describe.