# Why Protractor (in a Angular (v.4) project) doesn't find any spec to test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, angular-e2e

I'm working at an Angular (v.4) project and using Protractor I bumped into this issue

From the terminal:

> I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   Started No specs found Finished in 0.003 seconds
>
> I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>   [17:06:38] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

It runs the browser which get closed quickly, and it doesn't run (find) any spec.

protractor.conf.js:

```
require('ts-node/register');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',

  // use `npm run e2e`
  specs: [
    helpers.root('test/e2e/**/**.e2e.ts'),
    helpers.root('test/e2e/**/*.e2e.ts')
  ],
  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
  },

  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  },

  /**
   * Angular 2 configuration
   *
   * useAllAngular2AppRoots: tells Protractor to wait for any angular2 apps on the page instead of just the one matching
   * `rootEl`
   */
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

Folder structure

```
-/App
|--/config
   |--protractor.conf.js
   |--helpers.js 
   |--(all webpack files)
   |--(other stuff)
|--/node_modules
|--/src
|--/test
   |--/e2e
      |-mytest.e2e.ts
   |--/features
   |--/mockBackend
   |--/pages
      |-mypage.page.ts
   |--config.js
```

package.json

```
"cucumber": "^2",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.0.4",
"cucumber-snippets-tsflow": "^1.0.2",
"cucumber-tsflow": "^2.2.0",
"protractor": "^5.1.2",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^3",
"protractor-snapshot": "^1.2.0",
```

Comment: Yes, nothing to do

Comment: No mate, because helpers.root() resolves paths

Comment: ok well forget the helpers.root, its not working.  Get the basics working first. 
 are you telling me hardcoding `../test/e2e/**/*.e2e.ts` without `helpers.root` does not work??

Comment: yes, nothing to do

Comment: oh sorry i misread the folder structure.  There is no directory under `e2e`, any different with `../test/e2e/*.e2e.ts`?.  Deleted above comments to make room for these

Answer (score 1):

I Just recognized you probably execute `npm run e2e` as start command, indicating you're using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) or similar to run protractor. Therefore there could be issues in the run-command rather than in the path definition. As far as I could see there were some changes/issues in the way, protractor got started, i.e. [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4256).

I suggest to try these:

1. put your specs-part inside the `capabilities: { ... }`-part as this is [offered by protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L264). Maybe one of the angular-cli-configuration expects the there and not as a separate part
2. Use a config-helper-tool like [Cliptor.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cliptor) to create a new config-file and then compare for the differences to your file.
3. Start Protractor directly by executing the command `protractor protractor.conf.js` ([from the official protractor site](http://www.protractortest.org/#/)) instead of `npm run e2e` to verify/falsify if the problem is within `angular-cli` or within `protractor`.

Answer (score 0):

Any path starts from where `protractor.conf.js` is stored (so you start in the config-folder). Given the provided folder structure, I'll start with the normal path:

```
// use `npm run e2e`
specs: [
    //one level up, then below test/e2e/ all files ending with '.e2e.ts'
   // '../test/e2e/**/**.e2e.ts', //if *.ts is a file, no need for double ** 
    '../test/e2e/**/*.e2e.ts'  
],
exclude: [],
```

in case `**.e2e.ts` represents a folder and not a file your path should end `/**e2e.ts/*.js` (or whatever file-ending you chose for the test-file itself).

Also your `helpers.js`-file you should get as `var helpers = require('./helpers.js');`

And as I can't see, what's behind `this.root` I can't provide something for `helpers.root()`

Further could you want to use TestSuites or you might want to build a helper function, in which you can start from base-directory instead of relative-path to conf.js. Check out these links:

[Test Suites vs specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331018/suites-vs-specs-protractor).

[baseDir instead of relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491952/using-require-with-relative-paths).

Hope I could help.

Comment: **./helpers** is a js file inside **ProjectFolder/config/** folder

Comment: Did you then try `var helpers = require('./helpers.js');`?
Also what is the content of `this.root` in this case?

Comment: Yes and I get same error, I also tried with a normal path **specs:['./test/e2e/**/*.e2e.ts']**, nothing still getting that "error"

Comment: Is your test-folder inside your config-folder?
For normal path you start from the place of your conf.js.
`specs:['../test/e2e/**/*.e2e.ts']`

Comment: I added the folder structure and a part of package.json relevant Protractor and Cucumber

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you check, if it works for you now?

Comment: How do you run it?
`npm protractor conf.js`?
Do you have access to the folders, where you execute the tests and are the files available to you?
Can you add `console.log('this conf.js is executed')` to onPrepare to ensure the right file is called to start it all?